# How does rows per page for grid paging affects the site performance?

Tags: c#, jquery, performance, pagination

I want to get some advice to improve the performance of loading records in grid.

How does rows per page affects the performance?

For example for retrieving 100k records from database and displaying it in grid should I set rows per page 200 or i should set 50 per page.

Which will be more faster 200 per page or 50 per page ?

I believe 50 per page would be faster since it will have to send and receive less data and render on the page but at the same time it will need to do lot of computation as it has to divide and split into more pages.

Also where should I write the logic for spiting the  rows per page ? Should I write in business logic or in a stored procedure?

Also how does total number of the column displaying in the grid affects the performance ?

See the grid image below.

i would like to understand this as a performance stand point of view to get the best practice.

Comment: You should get the page of data from the database only. Retrieving 100k rows from database and then displaying only 50 of them give you very little performance benefit. The stored procedure should return only one page of data.

Comment: Yes..  performance also gets impacted by how many columns of data you want to display. So again you should display only relevant data in the gridview and retrieve only those columns from the database via Stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks. Which one would be more fast though 50 rows per page or 200 rows per page.

Comment: 50 rows per page will surely be faster...

Comment: That Chetan. 50 rows per page is faster.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use pagination rather than populating the entire grid at once.  If you set up your query right, it should be straight forward, you can easily query for a set limit of records and when the user clicks the next or previous button you simply pull those records only based on the filters, etc.  I wouldn't pull the entire dataset at once.